# Updating data of element in a listView

Tags: android-studio, listview

I'm trying to create an app for ordering cakes and bakes.

Therefore I have a list of deserts and a list of bakes in 2 different activities.

At the moment, once you click on a dish, its quantity will raise in 1. 
However, if I'm returning to the main Activity, and then again to the desert activity (or bake) then the quantity will initialize to 0, as I initialized each dish.

How can I change the dish qauntity of each view once you click on it, and it will be saved even if I leave the activity?

```java
public class DesertsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deserts_activity);

        final ArrayList<Dish> dishes = new ArrayList<Dish>();
        dishes.add(new Dish("Number Cake",180, R.drawable.cake_number, 0));
        dishes.add(new Dish("Ear of Haman", 40, R.drawable.ozen_haman, 0));
        dishes.add(new Dish("Alphachores", 35, R.drawable.alphachores, 0));
        dishes.add(new Dish("Snow Cookies", 35, R.drawable.snow_cookies, 0));



        DishAdapter adapter = new DishAdapter(this, dishes);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deserts_list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                dishes.set(position, new Dish(dishes.get(position).getDishName(),
                        dishes.get(position).getDishPrice(), dishes.get(position).getDishPic(),
                        dishes.get(position).getQuantity()+1));
                TextView quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(dishes.get(position).getQuantity()));

            }
        });
    }
```

and here is the adapter

```java
public class DishAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dish> {

    public DishAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Dish> dishes){
        super(context, 0, dishes);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

        }
        final Dish currenDish = getItem(position);

        TextView dishName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.dishName);
        dishName.setText(currenDish.getDishName());

        TextView dishPrice = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.dishPrice);
        dishPrice.setText(String.valueOf(currenDish.getDishPrice()));

        ImageView image = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.dishPic);
        image.setImageResource(currenDish.getDishPic());
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView quantity = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(currenDish.getQuantity()));

        return listItemView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short-lived storage (system-initiated state dismissal)

To preserve and restore activity's UI state, for example due to the screen rotation, change of language while activity is running, switching into multi-window mode, or any other system-initiated state dismissal you can override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. Then, once activity is re-created, you can extract this state from `Bundle` passed to activity's `onCreate` method.

> Saved instance state bundles persist both configuration changes and process death, but are limited by amount of storage and speed because onSavedInstanceState() serializes data to disk. Serialization can consume a lot of memory if the objects being serialized are complicated. Because this process happens on the main thread during a configuration change, serialization can cause dropped frames and visual stutter if it takes too long.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deserts_activity);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        // restore your data
    }

    //...
}
```

Then input `Bundle` parameter is essentially a `Map` which takes key-value pairs. Though be aware that there are situations in which this method is not being called. See the docs for [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) and [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

---

### Long-lived storage

To persist a state even after application is closed, consider using databases (SQLite, Realm, etc.), file, or shared preferences.

> Persistent local storage, such as a database or shared preferences, will survive for as long as your application is installed on the user’s device (unless the user clears the data for your app). While such local storage survives system-initiated activity and application process death, it can be expensive to retrieve because it will have to be read from local storage in to memory. Often this persistent local storage may already be a part of your application architecture to store all data you don’t want to lose if you open and close the activity.

See [Saving UI states](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)

Comment: So I don't really understood your answer since I'm new to this, is there any recommended tutorials regarding these saving methods?